# React update lifecycle methods return same props for date

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a component that receives new props, there is a weird behaviour occuring. The component will receive an Object and a date object.

Whenever the object is updated, in `componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState)` nextProps.someObject will return a different object as this.props.someObject, as expected.
However when the  date object is updated, this.props.someObject already contains the newly updated date that is stored in nextProps.

Am I missing something here regarding datatypes or referencing??

**EDIT**

With an example:

1. Render SomeComponent with date = 08/08/2017 and object with {name: "John"}
2. Update SomeComponent with date = 09/08/2017 and object with {name: "Doe"}

```
    SomeComponent date={newDate} someObject={newSomeObject}

    componentWillUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState){
        console.log(nextProps.date !== this.props.date); // at update: false
        console.log(nextProps.someObject.name !== this.props.someObject.name); // at update: true
    }
```

Comment: Add an example.

Comment: Are you updating both props at the same time? or maybe there are not synchronous so you would get 2 componentWillUpdate calls and maybe you're confusing the 2

Comment: No the props are update based on two different actions that are not occuring at the same time. So regardless of the javascript object, the this.props.date always equals the nextProps.date (being the updated value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Treat `state` as if it were immutable.

Try this code in your browser:

```html
var d = new Date();
var d2 = d;

d2.setDate(7);

d == d2;
```

`d2` and `d` is pointing to the same object.

Now asssuming you are getting your state:

`let newDate = this.state.date`

No matter what you update `newDate`, `this.state.date` is also changed. You can try yourself in your code.

Same situation applied to other data type like array.

I suggest to use [date-fns](https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns) as [the creator of Redux stated](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/805030922785525760?lang=en)